# escape character in vim command

Tags: linux, vim, shell

I want to run command like this:

```
vim -c "%g/blablabla/norm /str<ESC>cwSTR" file
```

How I write escape character in the command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you type the command, use <kbd>control-v</kbd> then <kbd>escape</kbd> to enter the escape.

However, I have to question whether vim is the right tool for this job.  Normally, you would be better off with something like sed.  That said, I'm not quite clear what the vim command is up to, so maybe you do need it.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is to replace last argument of some function. So I use vim facilities to navigate in code. The actual command is: -c "%g/fun_name//func_name<ESC>w%bcwREPLACE_TEXT". This search fuunction invocation, goes to the closing ), steps backward 1 word and replace the last argument.

Comment: Ok it works. I wasn't aware it works in bash too, I thought it works only in vim.

Comment: @idimba: I see why you're using vim for the job - it probably makes more sense than most other tools given what you are doing.

Comment: This works for setting `:inoremap jj <Esc>` in Vim's command-line.

Comment: I have to provide you bounty, such a superbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb answer. Save my day

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
vim -s -c ':exec "normal %g/blablabla/norm /str\<Esc>cwSTR"' file
```

Notice that I am using :exec to expand the "\" to the real . The advantage? it is more script friendly. However, I am not sure what this command is doing, are you using some of your custom maps here?